# why is variance having an effect on the flatmapto function?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am trying to understand this function:

```
public inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Array<out T>.flatMapTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> Iterable<R>): C {
    for (element in this) {
         val list = transform(element)
         destination.addAll(list)
     }
     return destination
}
```

if I swap `in` with `out` in `MutableCollection<in R>`, `destination.addAll(list)` stops working. The error is that `addAll` expected nothing.
Why doesn't it work? Clearly, `list` is an `Iterable<R>`, not an object of type `R`.
For example,

```
val list = listOf("abc")
list.flatMap{it.toList()}
```

As I see it, `Iterable<R>` is a `list of "abc"` and not "abc" itself. I mean the list of "abc" is not `R`, but the whole `Iterable<R>`. then why does `out` stops the code from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Out projected types can not use methods that consume an object of generic type

That is how [out projected types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) work. when you write `C : MutableCollection<out R>`, this means `C` is a producer of `R`'s, or in other words `C` is sub-type of a `MutableCollection` which can only have methods that produce `R` and it can not support any methods that consume `R` or any other generic type with type argument `R`.

since `destination` is of type `C`, you get the error saying `Nothing` was expected, signifying that consumer methods of this collection are not accessible.

using `in` makes it a consumer of `R`'s and hence you are able to use `addAll`, which is a consumer method in `R`.

Comment: My question is: `addAll` takes a parameter of type `R`, but why is `Iterable<R>`  passed?

Comment: @ntos [No it doesn't](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/add-all.html). `addAll` either takes `Iterable<R>`, `Sequence<R>`, or `Array<R>`.